# Prove foldl fusion law

Tags: proof-techniques, functional-programming, haskell

I have proven the `foldr` Fusion Law as follows:

Given `f` is strict, `f a = b` and `f (g x y) = h x (f y)` for all `x` and `y`, than

```
f.foldr g a = foldr h b
```

**Case `[]`**:

```
(f . foldr g a) [] = foldr h b [] -- Remove . notation
f (foldr g a [])   = foldr h b [] -- definition foldr
f (foldr g a [])   = b            -- definition foldr
f a                = b            -- This is a given, so stop
```

**Case `(x:xs)`**:

```
(f . foldr g a) (x:xs) = foldr h b (x:xs)       -- remove . notation
f (foldr g a (x:xs))   = foldr h b (x:xs)       -- definition foldr
f (g x (foldr g a xs)) = h x (foldr h b xs)     -- inductive hypothesis
f (g x (foldr g a xs)) = h x (f (foldr g a xs)) -- introduce y
                 say y = foldr g a xs
f (g x y)              = h x (f y)              -- This is a given, so stop
```

Now, I would also like to prove the Fusion Law for `foldl`. This goes like this:

Given `f` is strict, `f a = b` and `f (g x y) = h (f x) y` for all `x` and `y`, than

```
f.foldl g a = foldl h b
```

However, I don't seem to be able to use the same trick as in the proof for `foldr`. How can I prove the `foldl` Fusion Law?

Answer (score 7):

Let me try to answer your question, I may be mistaken, so check it out first:

Let's first state the definition of foldl:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl h b x = case x of 
                []     -> b
                (x:xs) -> foldl h (h b x) xs
```

Now, we aim to prove that, given `f:: A -> B, g:: A -> C -> A, h:: B -> C -> B, a:: A b:: B`, such that:

```
f a = b
f (g x y) = h (f x) y, for all x, y
f is strict
```

Then:

```
f . foldl g a = foldl h b :: [C] -> B
```

We are going to prove it by induction on the length of the list:

**Case 0:**

```
f.foldl g a []   = foldl h b []
f (foldl g a []) = foldl h b []   -- Definition of .
f a              = b              -- Definition of foldl
True                              -- given
```

**Case n => n+1:**

let `x:xs` be a list of length n+1, then xs has length n, the property holds for xs. Let's check it's true for `x:xs`:

```
f (foldl g a (x:xs))   = foldl h b (x:xs)
f (foldl g (g a x) xs) = foldl h (h b x) xs  -- Definition of foldl
```

Now, let's take `f' = f, g' = g, a' = g a x, h' = h, b' = h b x`

Clearly, `f'` is strict, also, `f' a' = b'`:

```
f' a'     = b' 
f (g a x) = h b x  -- Opening the '
h (f a) x = h b x  -- Hypothesis
h b x     = h b x  -- Hypothesis
```

Now, let's check that `f' (g' z y) = h' (f' z) y` works for any y, z (I changed the x for a z, because we have a fixed x, the head of the list):

```
f' (g' z y) = h' (f' z) y
f (g z y)   = h (f z) y   -- Opening the '
                          -- OK: hypothesis
```

Now, since the predicate works for lists of length n, and xs has that length, and also `f', g', h', a', b'` make the premises true, we have that, for any list of size n, in particular xs:

```
f' . foldl g' a' xs      = foldl h' b' xs
f  . foldl g  (g a x) xs = foldl h (h b x) xs  -- Opening the '
f (foldl g (g a x) xs)   = foldl h (h b x) xs  -- What we were trying to reach
```

Comment: Instead of saying "induction on the length of the list" it is better to describe what you're doing directly, namely [**structural induction on lists**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction).

Comment: @AndrejBauer This is natural induction on the length of the list, not structural induction. His inductive hypothesis is that `P(k)` is true, namely, `f . foldl g a = foldl h b :: [C] -> B` for the list of length `k`, and he must prove `P(k+1)` is true. Structural induction is used for things like trees or any recursively-defined data structure. You could say it's applicable to a cons-list depending on how it's defined, but that's like using integrals to find the area of a square. Structural induction is a generalization of natural induction. Note, the OP *did* use structural induction.

Comment: @BrainFRZ: I think I am well aware of what kind of induction is being used where. This answer says that it's using induction on the length of the list, but the induction step has the form of a structural induction: the induction hypothesis is used for `xs` and the result is then concluded for `x : xs`. That's structural induction. And you are quite mistaken with your analogy. Structural induction is *more basic* and *prior* to induction on the lenght of lists. This is an example from Haskell where lists are defined as a (co)inductive datatype, and that directly gives us structural induction.